# Read only synchronization

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronization, synchronized

*Effective Java - Item 66 (2nd Edition) states*

> In fact, synchronization has no effect unless both read and write operations are synchronized.

Suppose I have an object which is being updated by one thread and read by another thread. Synchronization on the read thread is needed for communication purpose, because as stated

> In other words, the synchronization on these methods is used solely for its communication effects, not for mutual exclusion.

But if the write is performed by a single thread, why can't we get away without using *synchronised* during write?

Comment: The communication mentioned is between the writer thread and the reader thread, not (necessarily) between the various readers.  In the answer below, this communication is called **happens-before**.  The write must happen-before or there's no obligation of the JVM to make the write visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of how **happens-before** works in Java Memory Model. To allow thread2 to see a new value of variable written by thread1 you need to establish **happens-before** relationship between this write and read (https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/core-java-tutorial/java-multi-threading/happens-before.html). One of the ways to do it is to use synchronization (`synchronized` blocks/methods, `volatile`, `AtomicXXX`) because releasing a lock always happens before acquiring of the same lock, write to `volatile` variable happens before subsequent read of the same `volatile` variable. And `AtomicXXX.set()` happens before `AtomicXXX.get()` for the same variable.